# SwiftUI - @State property is not updated

Tags: swiftui

I experience some weird behavior since updating to Xcode 12 / iOS 14. To verify this behavior, I isolated it in a test app.

In my original app, I have multiple `Sheet`s to control. This is why I have en `enum` to differentiate between the currently active sheet and I store this in a `@State private var activeSheet`. In the `@ViewBuilder` function `sheetContent()` I return the `View` for the selected `Sheet`.

For this test app, I only implemented one single sheet for simplicity reasons.

Here's the `ContentView`'s code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @State private var activeSheet = ContentViewSheets.State.none
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            activeSheet = .aSheet
            showingSheet = true     // <-- ISSUE: activeSheet is still set to .none here!
        }) {
            Text("Open Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet, content: sheetContent)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func sheetContent() -> some View {
        switch activeSheet {
        case .aSheet:
            Text("I'm the right sheet!")
        case .none:
            Text("Oops! I'm not supposed to show up!")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the enum:

```
class ContentViewSheets {
    enum State {
        case aSheet
        case none
    }
}
```

As commented in the ContentView code above, the value of the `activeSheet` property is never changed to `.aSheet`, but remains `.none` - so that the wrong sheet will be presented.

Is this a bug or didn't I properly understand Apple's `@State`? They just write in the documentation that it shall not be used in initializer, but only within the `body`, which I definitely do.

Comment: Having literally the same problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using two states, use one and explicitly designed sheet modifier for such scenarios.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
class ContentViewSheets {
    enum State: Identifiable {
        case aSheet
        case none

        var id: State { self }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var activeSheet: ContentViewSheets.State?
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            activeSheet = .aSheet
        }) {
            Text("Open Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { 
           sheetContent($0) // << activate state passed here !!!
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func sheetContent(_ state: ContentViewSheets.State) -> some View {
            switch state {
            case .aSheet:
                Text("I'm the right sheet!")
            default:
                Text("Oops! I'm not supposed to show up!")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great and thank you, Asperi! Very elegant solution! I'm still struggling to understand why mine was not working. Seems that I don't understand the nature of @State properties.

Comment: @Asperi you are a god. I was struggling with this issue for the last 4 hours... as for Ulrich, I have no clue why it does not work. I think its definitely a bug.